# R SQLDF how to handle NAs, missing values in operations such as divisions?

Tags: r, sqldf

I typically use functions such as `is.na` and `COALESCE` but I cannot find such as functions for R's SQLDF which makes its usage hard with messy data with missing values. Is there some way to force SQLDF to return NA in the case when NAs are occurring in the operations?

**How can you handle missing values and NAs with SQLDF?**

```
> sqldf('SELECT NA/13210')

Exception: no such column: NA
Show stack trace
> sqldf('SELECT NA/13210, 223423/NA')

Exception: no such column: NA
Show stack trace
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in the SQL string must be SQL, not R.  Use

```
sqldf('SELECT Null/13210')
##   Null/13210
## 1         NA
```

Here is noather example

```
dd <- data.frame(x = NA)
sqldf("select x/13120 from dd")
##   x/13120
## 1      NA
```

Comment: I am getting `<NA>` returned in the table from sqldf, how can I state that do not contain row with any NA with sqldf? I tried `col IS NOT NA`, `col IS NOT Null`.

Comment: As the answer says.  You must use SQL.   You can't use R in the SQL string. NA is R, not SQL.  Using the built in `BOD` data frame `sqldf("select * from BOD where Time is not null")` will return all columns since no row has an NA in the Time column.